# Forward Declaration of Classes in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, forward-declaration

I've written the following code I was going to run through to help me review inheritance and how dispatching/double dispatching works in C++ but it won't compile. I've looked up class prototyping/forward declarations and I've done that but I'm still getting an error "B is an incomplete type", "SubB is an incomplete type", etc.  What's the problem?

```
#include <iostream>

class B;
class SubB;

class A { 
    public:
        void talkTo(B b){
            std::cout << "A talking to instance of B" << std::endl;
        }
        void talkTo(SubB sb){
            std::cout << "A talking to instance of SubB" << std::endl;
        }
};
class SubA : A {
    public:
        void talkTo(B b){
            std::cout << "SubA talking to instance of B" << std::endl;
        }
        void talkTo(SubB sb){
            std::cout << "SubA talking to instance of SubB" << std::endl;
        }
};
class B { 
    public:
        void talkTo(A a){
            std::cout << "B talking to instance of A" << std::endl;
        }
        void talkTo(SubA sa){
            std::cout << "B talking to instance of SubA" << std::endl;
        }
};
class SubB : B {
    public:
        void talkTo(A a){
            std::cout << "SubB talking to instance of A" << std::endl;
        }
        void talkTo(SubA sa){
            std::cout << "SubB talking to instance of SubA" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

### EDIT

Changing the parameters to references made this work (help from R Sahu) but why doesn't this work now?

```
class A { 
    public:
        void talkTo(B &b){
            //std::cout << "A talking to instance of B" << std::endl;
            b.talkTo(this);
        }
        void talkTo(SubB &sb){
            //std::cout << "A talking to instance of SubB" << std::endl;
            sb.talkTo(this);
        }
};
class B { 
    public:
        void talkTo(A &a){
            std::cout << "B talking to instance of A" << std::endl;
        }
        void talkTo(SubA &sa){
            std::cout << "B talking to instance of SubA" << std::endl;
        }
};
class SubB : B {
    public:
        void talkTo(A &a){
            std::cout << "SubB talking to instance of A" << std::endl;
        }
        void talkTo(SubA &sa){
            std::cout << "SubB talking to instance of SubA" << std::endl;
        }
};

A a;
SubA subA;
B b;
SubB subB;

a.talkTo(b);
a.talkTo(subB);
```

Comment: You probably want to use pass-by-reference anyway, unless you never want to talk to anyone!

Comment: yep, in a real implementation for sure, but I just made this to see what type was coming through I'm not passing any sort of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a forward declaration, you can use the type only be reference: pointers and references are most obvious references.

Instead of

```
    void talkTo(B b){
        std::cout << "A talking to instance of B" << std::endl;
    }
    void talkTo(SubB sb){
        std::cout << "A talking to instance of SubB" << std::endl;
    }
```

use

```
    void talkTo(B const& b){
        std::cout << "A talking to instance of B" << std::endl;
    }
    void talkTo(SubB const& sb){
        std::cout << "A talking to instance of SubB" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot make a function call with forward declaration. If you need to make the function call, you have to move the implementation of the function. It needs to be implemented outside the class definition and after the definition of the classes. In your case, they need to be implemented after the definitions of the classes `B` and `SubB`.